# OCR reading O instead of 0 - C++, Opencv, tesseract

Tags: c++, opencv, image-processing, ocr, tesseract

I'm using Tesseract framework with Opencv and C++ to read letters from an image on windows platform. Result contains O instead of 0 in many scenarios. Is there any way to eliminate this and receive an accurate answer?

Comment: That's the j0y 0f 0CR. 1f y0u c0ntr01 the scann1ng 0f the 1mage, y0u m1ght be able t0 tweak scanner sett1ngs. 0therwise check 1f y0ur framew0rk a110ws y0u t0 set a d1ct10nary 0f val1d w0rds t0 a1d 1ts her1st1cs.

Comment: Use the other letter/digit around the O. If next to the O you detect a number than you can decide to convert it to a 0.If next to the O you detect another letter than keep the O.

Comment: @ Amitay Nachmani It can not be done since the sentence i'm trying to read contains both letters and numbers. Therefore the method you suggested is not applicable in my scenario. Is there any pre-processing techniques that can be applied before calling tesseract?

Comment: Do you find any solution for this? I am getting this issue. If my image have O0 and the result is: OO. Thank you very much for your sharing.